# Handling GET 301/302 responses with JavaScript in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-resource

I need to print some 301/302 response headers with JavaScript: I saw lots of answers for Angular, but I’m using Vue.js to get the results. Well, it doesn’t really matter since it’s mainly a JavaScript issue… I mean, **I’m not just interested in a Vue.js-*only* solution**, it could and should work everywhere. As a front-end developer, I can’t manually create a scenario in which my project returns a redirect in its own server and finding a random remote page that does it without CORS limitations is hard. To be even more clear, I need to get `status` code and `statusText` of 301/302 responses (as well as the `Location` of the new page) before the redirection, then the full headers of the redirected page. Now I can retrieve only these last, because [the default `this.$http.get();` request](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/develop/docs/http.md) created by `vue-resource` doesn’t seem to store the first in an object. What I’m asking here is if there’s a way to store the redirection response in a variable too, then to show both. I don’t know if switching to `axios` could be preferrable — since I’m pretty new to Vue.js. My component’s method is as follow:

```
getRequest: function() {
  this.$http.get(this.url)
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.ok) {
        if (response.status === 301 || response.status === 302) {
          // show the redirecting response
        }
      // show the redirected response
      }
    }
```

EDIT: [the sources for this project](https://github.com/fedtti/http-requests) are on GitHub; when you send a GET request and the response says 301/302, you should be able to see three columns instead of two where the second shows details of the redirecting response headers.

Comment: I would try using Axios just to make life easier but that probably won't change the response the server is giving you. However, I'm confused when you ask if there's a way to store data in a variable but don't want a Vue specific way of doing that. You can write the response to any defined variable so what's the issue?

Comment: You’re right, I mean… Vue.js is the framework I used for this small app, but I don’t need a specific solution for it: it was a test for a job interview (and I already got the job, anyway) that I really want to improve; what I need to do is printing the first, ready to be redirected, response in the component view as long as the final yet redirected one… to be clearer, `status` and `statusText` from both (301/302 in the first response, then 200) should be taken from the responses headers and saved in a variable I want to show on the page, but I got just the second.

Comment: Got it. Does `console.log(response)` give you both the status & statusText in the object? I'm 99% certain that those ARE in the `axios` response but it's been a while since needing more than the number.

Comment: Is this what you mean? https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/issues/714

Comment: Exactly, Eric! I’m wondering if switching to `axios` could do the trick, Bryce.

Comment: In my case, I had my request inside a middleware. Oops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not able no handle 301 or 302 status because those are inside the

```
if(response.ok)
```

block, which means that the status is 200. Try this instead:

```
   getRequest: function() {
  this.$http.get(this.url)
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.ok) {
      // show the redirected response
      }
      if (response.status === 301 || response.status === 302) {
          // show the redirecting response
      }
    }
```

Comment: It was so simple: I move the second case over the `response.ok` and it seems to work. I didn’t understand that `response.ok` standed for a 200 response, I thought it was more generic. Thank you so much!